Unable to connect to EC2 Instance in terraform , Timeout error shown
I'm facing a timeout error when I run terraform apply. Here’s what I’m trying to do:
I want to host my app on an Ubuntu server. To do this, I’m creating all the required resources using Terraform. However, when I run terraform apply, I encounter the following error:
│ timeout - last error: dial tcp 22.212.43.11: i/o timeout
# Specify the AWS provider and region for deploying the resources
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"  # AWS region where resources will be created
}

# Create an AWS key pair to allow SSH access to EC2 instances
resource "aws_key_pair" "keyone" {
    key_name   = "my-key"                 # Name of the key pair
    public_key = file("C:/Users/.ssh/xsec.pub")       # Path to the public key file
}

# Create a VPC (Virtual Private Cloud)
resource "aws_vpc" "cityvpc" {
    cidr_block = var.cidr    # CIDR block for the VPC, passed via a variable 
    enable_dns_support = true
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
       
}

# Create a subnet within the VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "citysub" {
    cidr_block = var.cidr_256             # Subnet CIDR block, passed via a variable
    vpc_id     = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id       # Associate the subnet with the VPC
    tags = {
      Name = "citysub"                    # Tag the subnet for identification
    }
}

# Create an internet gateway to allow public internet access
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "citygate" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id           # Attach the internet gateway to the VPC
    tags = {
      Name = "citygate"                   # Tag the internet gateway for identification
    }
}

# Create a route table to define routing rules
resource "aws_route_table" "cityroute" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id           # Associate the route table with the VPC

    # Add a route to allow all outbound traffic to the internet
    route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"          # Destination for all traffic
        gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.citygate.id # Route through the internet gateway
    }
    
}

# Associate the route table with the subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "cityrouteassn" {
    route_table_id = aws_route_table.cityroute.id  # ID of the route table
    subnet_id      = aws_subnet.citysub.id         # ID of the subnet to associate with the route table
}

# Create a security group in the VPC
resource "aws_security_group" "citysecurity" {
    name        = "TLS Allow"                      # Name of the security group
    description = "Allow TLS traffic"              # Description of the security group
    vpc_id      = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id               # Associate the security group with the VPC
}

# Ingress rule to allow HTTP traffic (port 80) within the VPC CIDR block
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "allowHTTP" {
    security_group_id = aws_security_group.citysecurity.id  # ID of the security group to apply the rule to
    cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"         # Allow traffic within the VPC's CIDR block
    to_port           = 80                                  # Ending port (HTTP traffic)
    from_port         = 80                                  # Starting port (HTTP traffic)
    ip_protocol       = "tcp"                               # Protocol: TCP
}

# Ingress rule to allow SSH traffic (port 22) within the VPC CIDR block
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "allowSSH" {
    security_group_id = aws_security_group.citysecurity.id  # ID of the security group to apply the rule to
    ip_protocol       = "tcp"                               # Protocol: TCP
    cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"                         # Allow traffic within the VPC's CIDR block
    from_port         = 22                                  # Starting port (SSH traffic)
    to_port           = 22                                  # Ending port (SSH traffic)
}


resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
    ami = "ami-0e2c8caa4b6378d8c" 
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.citysub.id 
    instance_type = "t2.micro" 
    key_name = aws_key_pair.keyone.id 
    associate_public_ip_address = true

    # SSH connection settings for provisioning the instance
    connection {
        type = "ssh"                      # Specifies the connection type (SSH)
        user = "ubuntu"                    # SSH user to log into the instance
        private_key = file("C:\\Users\\.ssh\\xsec")  # Path to the private key file for authentication
        host = self.public_ip                # The public IP of the instance for SSH connection
    }

    # Provisioner to copy the local file (app.py) to the instance
    provisioner "file" {
        source = "app.py"                  # Local path to the file to be copied
        destination = "/home/ubuntu/app.py"  # Destination path on the instance
    }

    # Remote-exec provisioner to execute commands on the EC2 instance
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [ 
            "echo 'Hello from remote server'", # Simple echo to confirm connection
            "sudo apt-get update -y",          # Update package list
            "sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y",  # Install Python3 package manager
        ]
    }

}






Hey Marko,
I have not found the resolution using the previous question posted, hence I would request you to please to open this question again. I'm stuck and need help badly.

You did get an answer though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79307748/8343484.
